# How can set unique key checking by another table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

i have create three tables: `supplier`, `item` and `purchase`. `supplier` id has relation with `item` table and `item` id has relation with `purchase` table. I do not want to insert `itemid` on `purchase` table in same `supplier` item. How can I set constraint?

```
CREATE TABLE csupplier(
  supid NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY ,
  supname VARCHAR2(30)
 );

CREATE TABLE ctitem(
  itemid NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  itemname VARCHAR2(50),
  supid NUMBER(10)
 );
ALTER TABLE CTITEM
  ADD CONSTRAINT CTITEM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(SUPID )REFERENCES CSUPPLIER(SUPID );
CREATE TABLE cPurchase(
  purchaseid NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  itemid NUMBER(10),
  purchaseqty NUMBER(10)
 );
ALTER TABLE CPURCHASE
  ADD CONSTRAINT CPURCHASE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(ITEMID )REFERENCES CTITEM(ITEMID )
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you add some examples of what should work and what shouldn't?

Comment: item-1 supA, item-2 supB  item-3 supA,  i don not want insert  item-1 and item-3  in a same time under purchase because item-1 and item-2 both are same supplier ,

Comment: i can set constraint unique supplier  in purchase table ?

Comment: There's no *supplier* in the *purchase* table, but - if you meant to create unique index (or a key) on cpurchase.itemid, yes, you can. By the way, punctuation exists for a reason; I suggest you use it.

Comment: Add example to the question instead of in a comment and explain what you mean with "in a same time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i don not want insert item-1 and item-3 in a same time under purchase

The problem is Oracle does not understand concept of *at the same time*. It understands transactions, it understands DML statements, it understands unique keys. So we need to frame your question in terms Oracle can understand: for instance, *a given purchase cannot have more than one item from the same supplier*.

Your first problem is that your data model can't support such a rule. Your `cpurchase` table has a primary key of `purchaseid` which means you have one record per item purchased. There is no set of purchased items against which we can enforce a rule. So, the first thing is to change the data model:

```
CREATE TABLE cPurchase(
  purchaseid NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE cPurchaseItem(
  purchaseid NUMBER(10),
  itemid NUMBER(10),
  purchaseqty NUMBER(10)
 );

ALTER TABLE CPURCHASEITEM
  ADD CONSTRAINT CPURCHASEITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY(PURCHASEID,ITEMID); 
ALTER TABLE CPURCHASEITEM
  ADD CONSTRAINT CPURCHASEITEM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(PURCHASEID )REFERENCES CPURCHASE;
ALTER TABLE CPURCHASE
  ADD CONSTRAINT CPURCHASE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ITEMID )REFERENCES CTITEM(ITEMID );
```

Now we have a header-detail structure which assigns multiple items to one purchase, which means we can attempt to enforce the rule.

The next problem is that `supplierid` is not an attribute of `cpurchaseitem`. There is no way to build a check constraint on a table or column which executes a query on another table.  What you are after is a SQL Assertion, which is a notional construct that would allow us to define such rules. Alas Oracle (nor any other RDBMS) supports Assertions at the moment.

So that leaves us with three options:

1. Go procedural, and write a transaction API which enforces this rule.
2. Denormalise `cpurchaeitem` to include `supplierid` then build a unique constraint on `(purchaseid, supplierid)`. You would need to populate `supplierid` whenever you populate `cpurchaseitem`.
3. Write an after statement trigger:

(Warning: this is coded wildstyle and may contain bugs and/or compilation errors.)

```
create or replace trigger cpurchaseitem_trg
     after insert or update on cpurchaseitem
declare
     rec_count number;
begin
     select count(*)
     into rec_count
     from cpurchaseitem pi
         join citem I on pi.itemid = i.itemid
     group by pi.purchaseid, i.supplierid having count(*) > 1;

     if rec_count > 0 then
         raise_application_error(-20000
            , 'more than one item for a supplier!');
     end if;
 end;
```

Frankly none of these solutions is especially appealing. The API is a solid solution but open to circumvention. The trigger will suffer from scaling issues as the number of purchases grows over time (although this can be mitigated by writing a compound trigger instead, left as an exercise for the reader). Denormalisation is the safest (and probably most performative) solution, even though it's not modelling best practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to your problem:
1. Alter the table cPurchase and add the supid column in the table. and make the unique key on this column. This will solve your problem.

```
CREATE TABLE cPurchase(
  purchaseid NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  itemid NUMBER(10),
  purchaseqty NUMBER(10),
  supid NUMBER(10) UNIQUE KEY
 );
```

2. If alter is not possible on this table, write a row level, Before Insert/update trigger. In this trigger write the logic to find the Supid based on the Item_id ctitem and them find any item on this supplier exists in your purchase table.

   ```
   CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER SUP_CHECK
   BEFORE INSERT
      ON cPurchase
      FOR EACH ROW 

   DECLARE
      L_COUNT NUMBER;

   BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT 
     FROM cPurchase c
     WHERE C.itemid in (Select itemid from ctitem ct where ct.supid = (Select supid 
      from ctitem  where itemid = :new.itemid)  );

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN ...
      -- exception handling

   END;
   ```